# How to look for click on the checkbox event on a specific cell on the workbook.

Tags: vba, excel, automation

Hi I have lots of sheets, in which I have a many cell on the column `AI`, which has checkbox in it.

I want to have an event handler on click of that checkbox on that column `A1`. I tried this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AI")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Hello World"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

this code works on click of the cell not on the checkbox.

How to look for click on the checkbox? And also get the row number of the checkbox being clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a macro to the Check Box. The below code will run when you tick a Check Box which the macro has been assigned to.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub check_box_ticked()
    Dim cbox As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, checkb as Shape
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set checkb = ws.Shapes("Check Box 1")
    cbox = ws.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value

    If cbox = 1 Then 'if message box is ticked then run code
        ' You can also use BottomRightCell
        MsgBox ("Row: " & checkb.TopLeftCell.Row & "Column: " & checkb.TopLeftCell.Column)
    End If
End Sub
```

This will return the column and row number when the Check Box is ticked.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What happens? Is it debugging? I tested it on excel 2010 and it worked.